# Macbook pro showing white screen after Apple logo

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro (Core i7 2.2 15" Late 2011) though the problem has happened before and was resolved when I did internet recovery. This solution no longer works. This happened last week when I booted the MacBook and it was displaying a white screen after Apple logo. Sometimes it shuts down after displaying the white screen for some seconds, and sometimes the Mac keeps restarting itself. I have tried PRAM & NVRAM reset, but nothing seems to work. Sometimes the logic board becomes hotter than normal. It’s really confusing. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Internet recovery lets you erase everything and install a new OS. Is that what you are looking to do? How are you measuring the logic board temperature - is hot 95 degrees C or something else?

Comment: Nope am not intending to erase it. When i put it on my lap i that’s when i feel the hotness. I know the temperature is abnormal, i mean extremely hot.